# Where to store the access token so it cannot be vulnerable to XSS

Tags: javascript, java, security, spring-security, xss

I am developing a web app and I am on a process of handling the Authentication of user. I am able to get the **access token** by initially making **HTTP POST** call to the API.

The idea know is where to store it so that it is not vulnerable to XSS.

Have heard of **HttpOnly** Cookie which makes it possible that the cookie is readable by the client (javascript), but the thing is why would I need something to store on my end when I cannot access it. How do I sent back to the backend (API) access token stored into coockie with http only since I cant get it so I am unable to attach it into headers of my **http request**.

Also, can I add a coockie with flag HttpOnly using javascript?

Comment: HttpOnly is for the server to set so the clientside can not alter the value....

Comment: @epascarello how am I suppose to send back the access token to the server using httponly? I mean can server set a coockie to store user access token , if so how do I send back access token to server from client when I dont have access into it! I am a bit confused here!

Comment: If you want to send it back do a post request or just request it from the backend to start.

Comment: @epascarello i dont think i got your point, post request I understand but what to attach on the post request? the last part just request it from the backend to start i dont think I have got this either, could u explain in more words or examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpOnly` means you cannot read it from Javascript on the client but the browser is still aware of that cookie and it is being added to any subsequent request you are making to the server.

It can be useful for an auth session cookie for example.
Session cookies are usually opaque tokens that are meaningless to the user and are meaningful only to the server. Thus there's no real reason why the client code would need to read them

> Also, can I add a cookie with flag HttpOnly using javascript?

No